# How to implement for-else and foreach-else in C# similar to Python's for-else and while-else?

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, if-statement

Python's *for* and *while* loops include an optional *else* clause which execute if the loop exits normally (*i.e.* without a *break* statement). For example, in Python you could code:

```
for x in range(3):
    print(x)
else
    print("The loop exited normally")
```

And the output will be:

```
0
1
2
The loop exited normally
```

How would you accomplish something similar in C# in order to code something like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);                  
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("The loop exited normally");
```

Comment: Unless you actually give full definitions of what these magical constructs do, the question aint real.

Comment: Sounds suspiciously [Pythonic](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)...

Comment: Give us the scenario you want to use these constructions, I bet you can always put a if - else around your for or foreach loop.

Comment: I doubt pseudo-code was what leppie had in mind about "full definitions"...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Python Construct for foreach-else is like this:

```
foreach( elem in collection )
{
    if( condition(elem) )
        break;
}
else
{
    doSomething();
}
```

The else only executes if break is not called during the foreach loop

A C# equivalent might be:

```
bool found = false;
foreach( elem in collection )
{
    if( condition(elem) )
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if( !found )
{
    doSomething();
}
```

Source: [The Visual C# Developer Center](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/8cb31277-eeaf-467a-a911-04c170982c45/)

Answer (score 6):

Sure:

- Use one of the fancy suggestions by the other posters
- Use a method that performs the loop, instead of `break`, you can `return` to avoid executing code below the loop
- Use a boolean variable you can set before you `break`, and test that after the loop
- Use `goto` instead of `break`

It's a weird pattern though if you ask me. "Foreach" is always started so the word "else" does not make sense there.

Comment: Aaargh - Goto. Really? <shivers/>

Comment: @JonEgerton, while I wouldn't quite use a goto here, I wouldn't condemn it either.  The python for-else construct is just a special case `goto`.  If you roll-your own goto, then you still have the same control of flow and have therefore not spagetified your code.   Touble is, that you might accidentally spagetify it in some later change.

Comment: I almost like the suggestion of goto, except it allows other code to enter it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're referring to [the for-else and while-else constructs in Python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), there is a basic `IEnumerable<T>` extension method that simulates a foreach-else described in [this article](http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/.net-for-else), with the following implementation:

```
public static void ForEachElse<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> action, Action @else)
{
    foreach (var i in source)
    {
        if (!action(i))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    @else();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Googling it gave me that : http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/.net-for-else

```
public static void ForEachElse<TSource>(
this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
Func<TSource>,
bool action,
Action @else
)  // end of parameters
{
foreach (var i in source)
  {
    if (!action(i))
      {
        return;
      }
  }
   @else();
}
```